# How to rescue data from RAM?

Tags: python, ram, raspberry-pi3

I'm looking for a solution to rescue data from RAM. 
My program terminated with an error and the data should still be in the memory.
Can I access it to save it somehow?

I'm working with python an a Raspberry Pi 3. My program scrapes data from the web and stores it in a csv-file. All data is scraped, but before writing it the program crashed. Executing the program again is not an option.

I ran the programm by calling it from the console, an error appeared and the console is waiting for my next input:

```
pi@raspberrypi: python3 program.py
"Error-message"
pi@raspberrypi:
```

Inside program.py my data was stored in a list 'data_list'.

How can I retrieve this list back?

**Editing:**

Executing the program again is not an option, because it took ca. 12h to complete. The scraped data would be used to make an educated guess for the runtime of a second program. By the time the scraping would have finished this guess is irrelevant.

Comment: Did the OS perform a core dump when your program terminated?

Comment: you cant do it actually, not from python at least. An assuming the data would be still in memory is assuming too much.

Comment: You probably won't be able to do this… Why is running the script again (after fixing it) "not an option"?

Comment: You'll probably need to hire a super-duper guru in Raspberry Pi or in Linux, so they could try to do this, but that will cost you a fortune. It's not easy at all to recover data from RAM, given that nobody knows its size or location. Moreover, this data has probably been overwritten hundreds of times by now, so, I think it's lost, and you should write your code carefully and handle the exceptions to make sure this doesn't happen again.

Comment: See the "Linux" section of http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Memory_Imaging for options in collecting memory

Comment: ...and if you want tools to help you actually make sense of that dump, [the Volatility Framework](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility) is your friend. But learning to use it properly will take more than your 12 hours of runtime, and there are no guarantees that the data's still there -- indeed, a well-behaved / optimized-for-security kernel will wipe pages as soon as they're returned to it.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could start reading memory addresses until you finally see something that looks like a CSV string. But this data would most likely be fragmented.

You could not do that in python, you'd need C or C++ and that'd take time to write.

**In practice**, by the time I'm posting this answer there is a very high chance that the pages your program used have been overridden by something else. Also due to process isolation you might not even be able to read all the memory.